# Hacer push en dos repositorios distintos

Tags: git, push

¿Hay alguna forma de hacer un push a dos repositorios distintos? Me explico. Estoy haciendo un curso de programación en el trabajo y el código lo publico en el repositorio oficial de la empresa, pero me gustaría que ese mismo código se publicara en mi repositorio personal.

He añadido mi repositorio a .git/config con `source`pero cuando hago el push, me da error de credenciales (cosa lógica, porque estoy usando el usuario y contraseña de la empresa.

¿Como puedo configurar correctamente ambas cuentas?

Comment: debes añadirlo con `git remote add` y especificar a qué "remote" haces el `push` o el `pull` como parte de estos comandos.

Comment: lo ideal es que hicieras un fork del repositorio para mantener la version una vez aprobado haces el merge de un repo con respecto al otro , asi es como funciona lo que quieres hacer

Answer (score 5):

Si estás usando el usuario y contraseña de la empresa, significa que el repo está usando una web url. Por ejemplo

```
 https://github.com/empresa/repositorio.git
```

Y ese repositorio es el `origin`. Eso puedes comprobarlo con

```
 git remote get-url origin
```

Si en cambio hubieses clonado el repo usando ssh, el comando anterior no te daría una url sino algo como

```
 git@github.com:empresa/repositorio.git
```

Usar un remoto ssh es más práctico porque te ahorras el tema de las credenciales. Pero para usar ese método necesitas una llave en tu carpeta `~/.ssh/`  y si no estás en linux no sé cómo se haría.

Volviendo al tema original. Tú tienes un repo que está en

```
 https://github.com/ik2_89/repositorio
```

Por lo tanto su web url sería

```
 https://github.com/ik2_89/repositorio.git
```

Para añadirlo no tienes que hacerlo editando manualmente el archivo `.git/config`. De hecho, edítalo de vuelta para que quede como antes. Para añadir tu repo como un remoto adicional, al cual le podemos llamar `alternativo`. Entonces le pondrías

```
 git remote add alternativo https://github.com/ik2_89/repositorio.git
```

Y luego podrías pushear a tu repo haciendo, por ejemplo

```
 git push alternativo master
```

En este caso te va a pedir credenciales, y tú ingresarás las tuyas propias y no las de la empresa.

**EDIT: ejercicio práctico.**

Voy a usar la url https para clonar el repo de [Canvg](https://github.com/canvg/canvg) (disclaimer, soy colaborador de ese proyecto)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esa url es ahora mi origin. Añado un segundo remoto apuntando a un fork de canvg. Siempre con http:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si hago un cambio y lo commiteo para forzar que haya algo que diferencie mi local del remoto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego si quiero pushear a `origin`, ingresaría mi usuario de empresa:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si en cambio quiero pushear a mi remoto personal (por ejemplo para sincronizar, lo hago explícitamente a `myremote` e ingreso mi correo personal:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si utilizaras llaves SSH también se puede, pero [hay que hacer un truco para que por debajo tu configuración de ssh sepa cuál llave usar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/59293/c%C3%B3mo-tener-dos-cuentas-de-git-en-un-mismo-equipo/59303#59303) acorde al remoto.

Comment: El problema es que como estoy usando la cuenta de la empresa, al hacer push al alternativo, me dice obviamente que el usuario de la empresa no tiene permisos sobre mi repositorio personal

Comment: pero estás usando urls ssh o http?

Comment: http, el caso que explicas

Comment: Bueno, al hacer el push alternativo cuando te pida autentificación, usa tu usuario personal. Déja editar esa parte a ver si se entiende mejor

Comment: para mi esta respuesta es valida, lo que quieres hacer en realidad es un fork del repositorio y llevat tus commit a tu otro repositorio

Comment: no necesariamente un fork, a veces tienes una copia de solo lectura que se va sincronizando con el origin, como en la época en que google code empezó a morir y los desarrolladores se previnieron creando repos "mirror" en github, que no los tocaron hasta que Google Code murió definitivamente.

Comment: He seguido tus pasos pero al hacer el `git push personal master`, en lugar de pedirme las credenciales me devuelve este error:

`git push personal master
remote: Permission to pablodelflores/100diasdecodigo.git denied to abaticst.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/pablodelflores/100diasdecodigo/': The requested URL returned error: 403
`

Comment: qué te dice si poner `git remote get-url personal`?

Comment: Me devuelve: `https://github.com/pablodelflores/100diasdecodigo`

Comment: Esa url te lleva a la página de tu repo, pero no es el endpoint que recibe los commits. El endpoint debiera ser `https://github.com/pablodelflores/100diasdecodigo.git` edita el remoto usando `git remote set-url personal https://github.com/pablodelflores/100diasdecodigo.git`

Comment: Igual, me sigue dando el mismo fallo.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86560/discussion-between-lk2-89-and-amenadiel).

Comment: He probado a borrar las credenciales de github de Windows y ahora, al hacer `git push personal master` me pide, lógicamente, las credenciales de mi cuenta.

Pero claro, si añado mi cuenta personal, después no podré usar la de la empresa, ¿no?

Comment: Oh, estamos hablando del cliente window. Claro, ese te guarda las credenciales en vez de pedírtelas cada vez. No sé cómo manejar ese caso, yo hago todo por línea de comando. ¿A lo mejor si instalas git bash?

Comment: Si, si... Si lo manejo desde Git Bash

Comment: En ese caso debiera preguntarte cada vez que haces push...